# Can we make the machine learn Gates (OR AND XOR etc.)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python

Below is the NAND Gate truth table, there are 2 independent features A,B and one dependent feature Y in the dataset.

Can we make the machine learn this if YES how ? if No why ?

Please go through the attempt below where the classifier model stumble on [0,0] point and can't predict it correctly giving .75 accuracy.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,classification_report,accuracy_score

x_train = [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
y_train = [1,1,1,0]

x_test = [[1,1],[1,0],[0,1],[0,0]]

clf_lr = LogisticRegression()
clf_lr.fit(x_train,y_train)
prediction = clf_lr.predict(x_test)

print(prediction) 
[1 1 1 1]

print(accuracy_score(y_train,prediction))
0.75

print(confusion_matrix(y_train,prediction)) 
[[0 1]
 [0 3]]

print(classification_report(y_train,prediction))


              precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
          1       0.75      1.00      0.86         3

avg / total       0.56      0.75      0.64         4
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer to the title question is "yes," many machine learning models are capable of learning various logical gates.  @KarelMacek is correct that the XOR gate is famously not linearly separable, so logistic regression will not be able to learn that one.

But your example is the NAND gate, which *is* linearly separable, so a logistic regression should be able to learn it.  The problem is that `sklearn` applies L2 regularization by default, which is preventing the model from learning the pattern "strongly" enough.  You can see from `clf_lr.predict_proba(x_test)[:, 1]` that the model has learned that $(1,1)$ is less likely to be a 1, but the regularization has prevented the probability from dropping below $0.5$.  You can reduce the regularization strength, or better set `penalty='none'`, to recover correct predictions.

Answer (score 1):

Ben Reiniger is right, but you also have an additional problem (a bug) that your `x_test` has a different ordering than `y_train`. You actually don't need `x_test` at all.

Here is the complete code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report, accuracy_score

x_train = [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
y_train = [1,1,1,0]

clf_lr = LogisticRegression(penalty='none')
clf_lr.fit(x_train, y_train)
prediction = clf_lr.predict(x_train)
print(prediction)
# [1 1 1 0]
print(accuracy_score(y_train, prediction))
# 1.0
print(confusion_matrix(y_train, prediction))
# [[1 0]
#  [0 3]]
print(classification_report(y_train, prediction))
#               precision    recall  f1-score   support
#
#            0       1.00      1.00      1.00         1
#            1       1.00      1.00      1.00         3
#
#     accuracy                           1.00         4
#    macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00         4
# weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00         4
```

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that XOR cannot be solved by a linear classifier (e.g. logistic regression):
http://www.ece.utep.edu/research/webfuzzy/docs/kk-thesis/kk-thesis-html/node19.html

Try to use SVM with either RBF or polynomial kernels:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html

Comment: I like random Forest because they have sharp edges. They’re decent at like this for that.

Comment: This is not the answer to the above question. A linear classifier CAN learn the NAND function. Regarding XOR, the classifier must be non-linear, but the question doesn't require linearity.

Comment: +1 because this _is_ an answer to the title question, even if it didn't seem to notice that the specific gate in the question was NAND.